# Generating documentation for a RESTful Web Service from Python

Tags: web-services, rest, documentation

I would like to generate documentation for a RESTful web service API that is written in Python. Ideally it would look like Yahoo's RESTful web service docs. Does anyone have any ideas or references?

Answer (score 2):

The Sphinx project ([www.sphinx-doc.org](https://www.sphinx-doc.org)) is the current state-of-the-art in Python documentation. It's really powerful and flexible... so also somewhat confusing. Still, I think it is your best bet.

There is excellent documentation on their site on how to set up the document source files and the process of building them in to finished documentation such as HTML. The part that should interest you is its system of incorporating docstrings from Python source, which I'm assuming you've been doing for the methods that serve your REST requests. Note that this will NOT magically interpret what is going on, but will bring all the named elements and their arguments (if appropriate) and provide a good framework for you to put in the appropriate documentation.

Assuming you have all of your REST functionality in a module named `restapi.py` and it is simply in your `src` directory of your project, you need to do two things to get Sphinx to automatically generate the documentation:

First, include the autodoc extension and add the `src` directory to Sphinx's path in `conf.py`:

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('sphinxext'))
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('src'))
```

Then in the Sphinx

```
.. automodule:: restapi
    :members:
```

Note: this information was taken straight from the Sphinx "First Steps" document with minimal reordering. Do have a look at that document and the rest of the site if this seems like it would serve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know anything specific that will help you in Python specifically -- However just as points of reference, you might take a peak at the WADL specification that the JAX-RS java spec is using -- https://wadl.dev.java.net/ -- Additionally, there is a xslt that will transform the wadl into html -- http://www.mnot.net/webdesc/

They use the yahoo REST API's as examples.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not making a REST API, but simply an RPC. There's generally no easy, automated way to assemble a REST API, which should primarily be a description of your media types.

If what you mean is that you want something to pull together all the URIs in your service and put them into an API document, that's not REST at all, due to all the coupling from URI to resources.